# Is arithmetic special for logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, incompleteness

I'm beginning learning logic, some theorems such as Goedel's two incompleteness theorems are stated as being "about" arithmetic. However as I understand things, other first order theories could give analogous results, some of those theories are much simpler like [this one of concatenation](https://www.impan.pl/%7Ekz/files/AGKZ_Con.pdf). Arithmetic is also used for examples such as what we can do with the completeness theorem. Is this purely because arithmetic was historically important or is there a deeper connection between arithmetic and logic?

Comment: I suspect PA is often used because it's a very natural theory (not some contrived example someone cooked up for technical reasons). The fact that it's incomplete in a strong sense is also why it's interesting for compactness examples; its models are pretty wild, so we can find lots of interesting phenomena among them.